# Dispatching `push` does not change route in React Redux Router

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux, react-router-redux

I'm working on a project with the React Redux Router, and am trying to change the page. When a component dispatches a "push" action, I see the `"@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE"` come through, but nothing changes.

I do have the routerMiddleware applied as well,

```
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
import rootReducer from '../reducers';

export const history = createHistory();
const middleware = routerMiddleware(history)
export function configureStore(initialState) {
  return createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    applyMiddleware(thunk),
    applyMiddleware(middleware)
  );
}
```

any thoughts as to what I'm doing incorrectly?

Comment: Not sure why, but it seems like switching the thunk and middleware lines fixes it? Would love an explanation as to why!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`applyMiddleware` expects a list of middlewares, so you're using it wrong: 
Please change it to:

```
export const history = createHistory();
const middleware = routerMiddleware(history)
export function configureStore(initialState) {
  return createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    applyMiddleware(thunk,middleware)
  );
}
```

This also explains why switching them worked (the store received another middleware).